# How can I handle method calls to an object that is a private property of another object?

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes, the Page class and the Template class. A page has a template associated with it, so it stores an object of the Template class as one of it's properties.

Here is my issue. These calsses are used in templating a page. If I want to include the template file, I would call `include $Template->view();`. However, since this object is a property of the a Page object, I have to call `include $Page->template->view();`.

This sticks me in the middle of two problems.

1. If I leave the `$Page->template` variable public, it could be overwritten at any point with something that isn't a Template object.
2. Make the `$Page->template` variable private, and I can no longer access it as I want to by calling `$Page->template->method();`.

From my point of view, the only option is wrapper methods in the Page class, such as `$Page->templateView();`.

I am the only one coding this, so option 1 is acceptable, as I will simply no overwrite it, but I wonder if there's a better way. If only there were properties that could be used publicly but not modified publicly.

Is there another choice for handling this type of thing?
Am I over thinking this or missing something?

Comment: what is `$Page->template`? Just a String, referencing the file name, like `/my/code/template/dashboard.html`?

Comment: @dognose `$Page->template` is an object of the Template class. That class holds various information regarding the template.

Comment: Template is part of a view, not the other way around ;-)

Comment: @Jack View was an arbitrary term I decided on for the files that hold the output. Each template has it's view, which is the actual HTML for that template, and then a script file in case that template needs to include any dependencies and such. Just trying to make a simple little template system and separate the output from the actual logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

a) Make a public accessor method and call it like so:

```
class Page
{
    private $template;

    public function template()
    {
        return $this->template();
    }
}

// call it like this
$page_object->template()->method();
```

b) If you don't like using "template()" instead of "template", you can take advantage of magic methods:

```
class Page
{
    private $mTemplate;

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if ($name == 'template')
            return $this->mTemplate;
    }
}

// call it like this
$page_object->template->method();
```

Comment: I considered the __get() method and couldn't make up my mind. However, great examples. The first option is so simple yet it didn't even cross my mind. I should have thought of that. Thank you for reminding me to stop over-thinking things! I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

In order of incapsulation (in order to hide 'template' property of Page class) you should

1. make the property private
2. add get-method which returns value of the property
3. do not add put-method to not allow updates of property value

As a result you'll get a read-only property.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Too bad there isn't an actual read-only property functionality. It would be an excellent addition. However, in this case I need to have a put method but wanted to avoid calling a get method every time I need to use a Template method. However, it looks like that's what I'm going to have to do. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it is possible to access to a private property through a public method. Just create a method that returns the property and call like this:

$Page->getTemplate()->methodOfTemplate();

Additionally it alows to pass some argumets on getTemplate call and e.g. customize something before returning template property

Comment: I agree with you. I was simply over thinking the problem. I wanted to access the template like a public property but prevent it from being modified as if it was private. In the end, a get method is good enough. As you demonstrated. And good point about passing argument to getTemplate(), that's a perk I didn't consider. Thank you for your response.